# Java socket does not timeout when severing the connection

Tags: java, linux, sockets, timeout, xmpp

I am seeing some strange issue with my automation tests.

There is a following setup:
Server: Centos 6
Client1: Windows 7
Client2: Centos 6

I'm writing the test that simulated connection disruption to server by blocking the outbound connection on server's `iptables`. But, the behavior of socket differs on Windows from one on Linux client.

One thing though, in both cases there is a line of Java code that does:

```
socket.setSoTimeout(0)
```

### Scenario #1 (Windows):

- send the `ssh` command to server `iptables -A OUTPUT --dport XYZ -j DROP`
- After approximately 60 seconds my console says `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`
- Connection drops

### Scenario #2 (Centos)

- send the same command as above
- I tried waiting as much as 10 minutes but console **never** outputs the exception.

So, **the question**, is there a way to make the behavior of socket the same (or approximately the same)?

I read that `Windows` actually does not use `SO_TIMEOUT` but `SO_RCVTIMEO` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [setSoTimeout(int timeout)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout-int-):

> Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in milliseconds. With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a read() call on the InputStream associated with this Socket will block for only this amount of time. If the timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the Socket is still valid. The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking operation to have effect. The timeout must be > 0. **A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout**.

Are you able to set a realistic timeout value?

Comment: I probably am, but what was weird for me that `Windows` does not honor the infinite timeout. I am a bit afraid, by changing the timeout, not to ruin hundreds of existing tests which use this connection class as well.

Comment: Check also **The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking operation to have effect.**

Comment: Thanks, that was crucial piece of info. Upon observing the behavior I was able to resolve  this issue in a different way... Adding the answer now...

Answer (score 0):

After reading David's answer I observed the behavior of that socket in order to see how does it work.

As David stated, SO_TIMEOUT only applies to future `read()` calls and not the ones that have already been called.

The common pattern for my tests was:

- Connect the user (socket)
- Exchange some data
- Server does not communicate with user for some time
- At this point client has already entered the `read` method. Setting `SO_TIMEOUT` at this point is useless.
- Block the server's OUTBOUND traffic on local port (some random 55000+ port)
- Wait for `SocketTimeoutException`

If I was to set the `SO_TIMEOUT` **before**, my socket would throw the exceptions like mad. So, I was hoping and was wrong when excepting for exception to be thrown in case of network outage. On the contrary, exception is being throw in case of **traffic** outage.

Can this be an issue with `Keep-Alive`? My socket sets it to `true`.

### Solution (empiric):

I measured (on Windows) that it takes approximately 60 seconds for socket to go down.

So, when I need to sever the connection, I create a thread that checks every 2 seconds if current time is greater from `(creation time + 60s)`. When it reaches that time, it invokes `socket.close` which effectively causes `SocketException`.

This solution is by no means optimal but it will have to do, at least for now.

Hope this will be of any help to someone else out here..